# SQL parser and XML

Tags: java, sql, xml, parsing, antlr4

Here what I want to do : develop a project (using java), so I can be able to create an xml file (output) who define the select clause from SQL Query (input)

I was searching a lot and realise some points (please correct me if I'm wrong)

- I found that with ANTLR and from a text input I can have the parse tree, now I was able to create my own parser
- I think that I need a schema or DTD to define the structure of my xml file and I'm able to do that too

But now I'm lost on how to build every clause dynamically, I mean how can I get the specific tokens and put the them on the right position in XML tags

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

For a more precise answer, please specify which database you are using, and give a (simplified) example of what you are trying to do.

If I understand correctly you have some database that you want to query and produce XML output. In this case, please look at SQL XML functions:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL/XML

"Examples" section of that page shows the use of XMLELEMENT, XMLAGG, and XMLATTRIBUTES functions in SELECT clause. That may be useful in your case.

Comment: Hi @Andrey. well, first of all parse the sql query (select statement), and then generate an xml file that contain the select clauses.  for example if the select statement is "select addres, email from employe", then the XML file should be something like that:  
<statement>
  <columns>
     <attribute> address </attribute>
     <attribute> email </attribute>
  </columns>
  <table> employe </table>
  <condition>  </condition>
</statement>

Comment: sorry for not formatting the text which present the XML, I don't know how, I'm new in this awesome stackoverflow

Comment: @Great, sounds like you want XML output to include both query results (which you can do with SQL/XML functions I listed above) AND the query itself, which is a lot trickier. There was a similar question here with some ideas, but no great answers:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6569782/api-or-tools-to-convert-sql-select-queries-into-xml-form

Comment: Hi @Andrey, thanks for your replay and thanks for the link it was useful. Actually what I want to do is not quite that, but I what to make XML like my intermediate trick so I can use it to other stuff